# including refs in git pretty format string

Tags: git

Is it possible to specify a format string which outputs the refs/heads/* just like

```
$ git log --decorate=full --oneline --source --all
```

outputs

```
1e6904c refs/heads/master (HEAD, refs/heads/master) Merge branch 'release/2.0.0'
bad9644 refs/heads/develop (tag: refs/tags/2.0.0, refs/heads/develop) Merge branch 'hotfix/1.0.1' into develop
d844f6c refs/heads/master Merge branch 'hotfix/1.0.1'
```

My starting point is:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%d %h %p % " --all --source
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The `%d` directive does what you want, but *only* if you specify `--decorate=full` as well.  I found this unclear in the documentation (it says `--decorate` does this, but only `--decorate=full` does the trick:

```
$ git log --decorate --format='%h %d' | head -2
d34ab33  (HEAD, master)
0c14692 
$ git log --decorate=full --format='%h %d' | head -2
d34ab33  (HEAD, refs/heads/master)
0c14692
```

Comment: This only shows the full refs path, but what's still missing is the ref fot 0c14692 in your example.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was concentrating only on the `%d` part being short instead of full.

Answer (score 0):

Git does not support combining `--source` with custom format strings. I checked this in the sourcecode a while ago.